# Get external js via unauthorized https in browser extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, microsoft-edge

I am developing a chrome extension which I gonna realize in Edge and Firefox in near future. I need to implement an external js file which is uploaded on my server. Chrome needs a https connection so I set up ssl on my Amazon EC2 Linux server. When I try to open it via chrome directly, chrome is warning me because the connection is not authorized. But when I run my extension it gets the js file without problems.

So my question is: Is it ok (in Chrome, Firefox and Edge) to get this external js from my server via an unauthorized https connection or do I need to authorize it (whatever this means I am not really into this).

Comment: Why cant you package it?

Comment: Firefox: An add-on that does this will not pass review by [AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/). For security reasons, all JavaScript that is run by the extension **must be included in the extension package**. This even includes normal libraries (e.g. jQuery, etc.). Any such libraries included in minimized form must match *exactly* the distribution provided by the ultimate source of the library (they will be compared byte for byte). It is certainly technically possible to accomplish this, but doing so is automatically considered nefarious.

Comment: Then I gonna package it or feed the extension via php and post messaging. It would be nice if I could update some variables without updating the entire extension.